# Heroku R10 (Boot timeout) - Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, heroku-cli

So I have got into this problem while deploying my website with heroku. I have seen other solutions in which I have tried to change the scripts in package.json and Procfile aswell but no luck for me Please help me. This website runs well locally
Here is my index.js main function

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
const fact = facts.space
res.render("home", {fact: fact});
});
```

Here is my listen function.

```
const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT
app.listen(port, function () {
console.log("@ working");
})
```

Here is my packages.json
[packages.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDuge.png)
Here is my Procfile
[Procfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnUaZ.png)
Here is the error that I am getting
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwl2p.png)
Here are all of my files [All files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqvBY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invert the definition of the port to check first the `$PORT` env variable, then fall back to the default port number (`3000`) in case it does not exist (ie on local development environment)

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
```